# Installing Crystal with my app - What's involved?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

We've written a C# app that will display Crystal 2008 reports in the .NET Crystal viewer. Can anyone tell me what's required for installing the Crystal runtime files on each client machine to support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime files needed should be on your machine in a path similar to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages.  There should be a crystal folder that contains the files you need.

Whatever you do don't go to the crystal reports site and get to try and get the runtime files.    The ones on that site are for the full paid version.  Not the version that comes with Visual Studio.